# Derive the Cramer-Rao lower bound for variances of unbiased estimators of a 99th percentile

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

A certain general insurance portfolio has a light-tailed loss distribution with a probability density function given by:

$$f(z, \lambda) = \lambda e^{- \lambda z} ; z>0, \lambda > 0$$

An important quantity of interest in relation to this portfolio is the 99th percentile of this loss distribution.

Derive the Cramer-Rao lower bound for the variances of unbiased estimators of this percentile.

Some background: I am used to using a method of finding the CRLB for an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ for example in the original p.d.f but this idea of finding a CRLB for a percentile is very new to me and I was hoping I could get some input in order to understand this concept.

So here's what I would've done (ignoring the percentile part and hoping it doesn't make a difference :/)

$$\text {Suppose } t(Z) \text { is unbiased for } \lambda \text { i.e.}$$

$$E[t(Z)] = \lambda = \tau(\lambda)$$

$$\tau '(\lambda) = 1$$

$$lnf(z, \lambda) = ln(\lambda) - \lambda z$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial {\lambda}} lnf(z, \lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda} - z$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial {\lambda}^2} lnf(z, \lambda) = -\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$

$$i_E (\lambda) = - E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial {\lambda}^2} lnf(z, \lambda)] = -E[-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}] = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$

$$\text {Where } i_E(\lambda) \text{ is the Expected Fisher Information}$$

$$var(t(Z)) \geq \frac{[\tau ' (\lambda)]^2}{n \times i_E(\lambda)} = \frac{1^2}{1 \times \frac{1}{\lambda^2}} = \lambda^2$$

Idea: Should I maybe find the cumulative distribution function $F(z, \lambda)$ and do it basically the same but when finding Fisher Information use $lnF(z, \lambda)$? The fact that they specifically refer to the 99th percentile confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $0.99$-percentile is the solution to equation 
$$
F(x_{0.99},\lambda) = 0.99, 
$$
where $F(x,\lambda)$ is the cdf; $F(x,\lambda) = 1- e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$. It is easy to find 
$$
x_{0.99}(\lambda) = \lambda^{-1} \log 100.
$$
Thus, by the Cramér–Rao inequality, for any unbiased estimator $\hat x_{0.99}$ of $x_{0.99}$,
$$
\mathsf{Var}_\lambda(\hat x_{0.99})\ge \frac{(x_{0.99}'(\lambda))^2}{I(\lambda)} = \frac{(\log100)^2}{\lambda^4 I(\lambda)}.
$$
I think you can finish this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see now that the property of interest of percentiles can only be affecting $\tau(\lambda)$ in my notation where the Fisher information will not be affected because it is always just based on the unknown variable $\lambda$ right

Comment: @StephanCasey, Fisher information does not depend on the function being estimated, that is correct.